# .htaccess File not working properly for static/wordpress site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, routes, server

I have had a heck of a time trying to make a very simple website carry a wordpress as a sub directory so we can use it only as a blog. 
To make this simple and quick, I will break this down into three parts.

What you need to know: All pages are in the root.

- I have the following .htaccess rules implemented to chop off all .php in the url so the url is cleaner, in the first example A) below. This is not an issue.
- However the second example B) is my attempt to ignore /blog. This is so not to effect blog's contents/files etc.. when I pop off the .php, and allow it to operate on its own since its wordpress and has its own frame work. This is not working. What am I doing wrong, how would you correct this?
- Lastly, once corrected I want anything beind serverver from blog to chop off the blog part in the url and have the site read http://website.com/whatever, not http://website.com/blog/wwhatever, how can I work that in?

Please help, I have been at this for days and Im so lost!

**Example A)** take off the .php:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# rewrite css, js and images, from root
RewriteRule ^abc/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]
```

**Example B)** Avoid /blog in order to not disturb wordpress, and in return it cannot override our files root files:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ![/blog]$ ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# rewrite css, js and images, from root
RewriteRule ^abc/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]
```

Also, The sub directory has a .htaccess it is:

```bash
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Where are all these mod_rewrite directives - in a single .htaccess file off the root? Where are the WP directives? Is WP installed in a subdirectory, or do you just to make it look like it's in a subdirectory? Is the whole site WP or just the blog?

Comment: Hi @w3dk Thank you for the quick response. So these are in the root. The .htaccess I have in the sub directory blog/ is the one that was over at godaddy and looks like... The above, I edited it to add the blog/ .htaccess I know it is repeating, don't know why they did it this way!